# Search using ObjectID with MongoDB jdbc

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc

I have a Pojo object on which I store the ObjectID retrieved from Mongo. 
When I print it, I can see this:

```
Object: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5a4b939225c218fbe107199c" }, "organizationId" : "ORGANIZATION_ID", "organizationName" : "Organization name", "storeIds" : [] }
```

I want now to search using the ObjectID and I'm using this:

```
public String find(String dbId, String collection, ObjectId id) throws Exception {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", id);
    FindIterable<Document> search = collection.find(query);
}
```

The problem is that search is always null. How can I search using ObjectID? Is there a way to do without extracting the oid and creating the query in this way?

```
query.put("_id", new ObjectId(oid));
```

Comment: How are you creating the ObjectId that is being passed to your find method ?  What does `query.toJson(new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.EXTENDED))` output for you ? btw you should use `Document` not `BasicDBObject` in 3.x driver.

Comment: It prints this: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5a4bcfabb13b0907b7a9c5d4" } }

Comment: It's mongo that automatically creates the ObjectID when I save the object.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. So where exactly is the problem. while searching or saving ? Unless I'm missing something the ObjectId you printed that is passed to method is different from what you get when you print saved document's ObjectId. So no match happens.

Comment: Problem is searching. When I pass the ObjectID is translating into something different. I should extract the $oid then create a new ObjectId() passing the oid.

Comment: You shouldn't and to my knowledge you can't through java driver unless you read the raw json and extract the oid. Use the helper methods provided in the ObjectId class. ObjectId's toHexString() will give you the hex string for you to pass around. Ids created through hexstring should be able to roundtrip between server and client. Btw How do you prepare the id ? Do you just use hexstring and create new ObjectId(hexstring) before passing to mongodb for search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first, when the I fill the Pojo and ObjectID is filled with the values retrieved from MongoDB, a new object is created so, it will be different than the one retrieved.

What I have done is to create a new DataType, adding these two classes:

```
public class MongoOID {

    @SerializedName("$oid")
    private String oid;

    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }

    public void setOid(String oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }
}

public class MongoId {

    @SerializedName("_id")
    private MongoOID _id;

    /**
     * http://www.baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api
     */
    private LocalDateTime created;

    /**
     * http://www.baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api
     */
    private LocalDateTime updated;

    //region Getter and Setter
    public MongoOID get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(MongoOID _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(LocalDateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(LocalDateTime updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }
    //endregion
}
```

So, on my Pojo, I replaced ObjectId _id with MongoID _id and I'm able to read the proper ID. 
When I use this ID to query mongo, I simply use this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));
```

where id is a String and it is :

```
organization.get_id().getOid()
```

I'm not sure this is the better way (and probably the correct neither) but it works. Unfortunately, I do not have the creation timestamp so I have had to add two key to my document (created and updated).

Answer (score 0):

Try as,

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public DBObject findDocumentById(String id) {

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));

    DBObject dbObj = collection.findOne(query);
    return dbObj;
}
```

You can find one or all the similar object ids.

Comment: That's not working. As mentioned the problem is how to extract the obtain the String id from ObjectId. I tried also with hex but without success.